# Write text file for each windows event log

Tags: windows, batch-file, event-log

I'm trying to write a text file for each event with id 4663, so from the event log I've scheduled a task that runs a batch file with argument 4663. This is my .bat:

```
@echo off
IF /I "%1" EQU "4659" set ACTION=Lan Delete
IF /I "%1" EQU "4660" set ACTION=Local Delete
IF /I "%1" EQU "4663" set ACTION=Evento Object
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%" & set "Mil=%dt:~15,3%"
set TIMESTAMP=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%%HH%%Min%%Sec%%Mil%
set HOLDER="C:\log\Evt%1_%TIMESTAMP%.txt"
set LOGFILE="C:\log\logEvents.txt"
type nul > %HOLDER%
wevtutil qe security /rd:true /q:"*[System/EventID=%1]" /f:text /c:1 > %HOLDER%
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('type %HOLDER% ^| find /i "Account Name"') do set accname=%%a
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('type %HOLDER% ^| find /i "Event ID"') do set eventid=%%a
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('type %HOLDER% ^| find /i "Date"') do set dt=%%a
set HEADER=%eventid%: %accname% / %ACTION% @ TS: %dt%
echo %HEADER%
echo %HEADER% >> %LOGFILE%
```

This script correctly generates a generic log file and a file for each event using the timestamp to make sure you do not miss any events.

For example, when copying a file, it generates two 4663 events, one for "WriteData" and one for "AppendData".

Unfortunately, the result of the query is the same for the two files, it always takes the first 4663 event it finds.

Even worse if I try to copy 3 files I will find 6 events 4663 but all pointing to the data of the first file.

If instead I copy a file at a time at least the double refers to the single file.

The only certainty I have is that for each event 4663 I create a text file so the scheduled batch is executed on time.

I think it's a problem of the query because if I try to run it from cmd it gives me a result only that corresponds to the first event 4663 of the event log.
I don't know if during the event scheduling I can pass the id handle of the event as an argument of my .bat task.

For the security, I have to recover the event as soon as it is registered because it could sabotage the PC in some way or even delete the security events log before I can check it.

Any idea?

Comment: FYI, your `type nul > %HOLDER%` is redundant and can be removed, because the line beneath it writes to the same new file. I would also look at reading `%HOLDER%` only once and extracting all of the data needed during that read, _it will make the script quicker/more efficient_. You may even find that to writing your information directly to `%LOGFILE%` instead of setting the data to variables first is more effective too, as it will write all found entries, not just the last one read, _this sounds like the reason for the issue you're reporting in your question_.

Comment: With the `/c:1` argument you instruct wevtutil to return only one event.

Comment: Well spotted, @LotPings, I thought it was odd that they stated that it was returning the first matching event, whereas, the loop, as they currently have it, would normally have returned the last matching event. I suppose that as the default output format is already `text`, they could also remove the `/f:text` option too.

Comment: I'm really beginner on the subject, I just assumed that starting the script along with the event and asking for the most recent result with that id event I got a txt with the details of the event itself.
This test I need to understand if I extract the data correctly because then I will replace everything with direct writing on db in mysql

Comment: IMO PowerShell and the event log related cmdlets  are better suited for your task. `Get-WinEvent Security | Where ID -in (4659,4660,4663) | Select-Object -First 10`or `Get-EventLog Security -InstanceID (4659,4660,4663) | Select-Object -First 10` You can then further expand/interrogate properties.

Comment: I dont't know powershell...can you help me? I think that your "query" extract first 10 rows for where condinion but I I would like for a specific event to be written a text file that contains all the data of the event ... this is why from the event log for a certain event I created a scheduled task .bat, only that at this point I doubt you can know a unique ID and therefore pass it as an argument to the task to execute a query with powershell